# Selenium MouseDown error with Webdriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, automation, webdriver

I'm using webdriverbacked selenium, and it was workign fine, even the mouseDown commands, when i abruptly get this error:

com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: TypeError: b is undefined
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

I have no idea how it got here, but the mouseDown commands won't work anymore. Any idea why this is happening and how to resolve this?

Comment: could you plz post a little code snippet?

Comment: Can you please post your single line code for mousedown ?